# Can I upload a html file with Google Documents List API?

Tags: gdata-api, gdata

I need to upload html files to google docs with Google Documents List API, but the server always response an error of "ServiceForbiddenException".

the header is:

POST /feeds/default/private/full HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: OAuth 1/VbdXxNS9HXN1Q3pe8D....
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Slug: test.html
Content-Length: 2109

....content.....

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be an HTTPS URL? Can you show more of the URL that you are using?

I found the `java/samples/DocumentList.java` tutorial included in the gdata release very helpful in hunting down these things.